# How to get an event when the user selects text in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp WinForms v43 to allow users to select text on displayed web pages. I need an event everytime "text is selected", so I'm using JS to hook the `onmouseup` event and trying to pass the selected text as a return value from JS to C#. But everytime I select something on the web page the browser hangs up the UI thread. If I omit the arg the event fires. Is there any way to get CefSharp to call a C# method from JS while passing an arg?

I'm doing this to init:

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com"");
browser.RegisterJsObject("jsObject", this, false);
```

I'm doing this on `FrameLoadEnd`:

```
 browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
     document.body.onmouseup = function(){
         jsObject.OnSelected(window.getSelection())
     }
 ");
```

And so when the user selects some text on the page, this method should fire:

```
 public void OnSelected(string selected){
     MessageBox.Show("The user selected some text [" + selected + "]");
 }
```

Strangely enough when I try with a literal value my C# handler fires.

```
 browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
     document.body.onmouseup = function(){
         jsObject.OnSelected('hello world')
     }
 ");
```

Comment: `browser.RegisterJsObject("jsObject", this, false);` produces a compiler error: "cannot convert from 'bool' to 'CefSharp.BindingOptions'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, CefSharp can only marshal primitive values as args. Ensure your selection is a string and the event should fire. Works for me.

Change your code in `FrameLoadEnd` to this:

```
 browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
     document.body.onmouseup = function(){
         jsObject.OnSelected(window.getSelection().toString())
     }
 ");
```